# determine two-term outer, inner and uniform expansions

Tags: asymptotics, boundary-value-problem

Consider the equation;

determine the two-term outer, inner and uniform expansions assuming that $0<\epsilon<<1$ 
$$\epsilon \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0, \hspace{5mm} y(0)=0,\hspace{2mm}y(1)=1$$

I have worked out the exact solution of why but don't know if that applies here?
I have also found by setting $\epsilon=0$ that the first order outer layer term is $\exp(1-x)$. I know how to work out the first term for the inner layer aswell, but could someone explain how to work out the second terms.

Answer (score 2):

To get the first term, you took the smallest powers of $\epsilon$. To get the second terms, take the second smallest terms. I'll go through the outer solution.

Let $y=y_0+\epsilon y_1+O(\epsilon^2)$, so 
$$ \epsilon y_0''+\epsilon^2 y_1'+y_0'+\epsilon y_1'+y_0+\epsilon y_1=0. $$
The smallest power of $\epsilon$ is $0$, so the leading order equation is 
$$y_0'+y_0=0,$$
the next order equation is $O(\epsilon)$,
$$y_0''+y_1'+y_1=0,$$
and you can continue this as far as you want.

Once you know $y_0$, you can use it to find $y_1$, then use that to find $y_2$ and so on.